# Sum of multiple index matches with tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the sum of associated columns from multiple different tables.

This works for one table, `=INDEX(Table2[@W],MATCH([@[Franchise ID]],Table2[@[Franchise ID]],FALSE),1)`

However when I try to add a second table, it throws an error `=SUM(INDEX(Table2[@W],MATCH([@[Franchise ID]],Table2[@[Franchise ID]],FALSE),1),INDEX(Table224[@W],MATCH([@[Franchise ID]],Table224[@[Franchise ID]],FALSE),1))`

How can I make this work?

Comment: What error? `#N/A`? Your formula should work I think, so probably there simply isn't a match. Somehow the value you looking for isn't in your table. Leading/trailing spaces or text looking like dates more than once are the culprit of these issues.

Comment: May I ask why you not using SumIfs?

Comment: @JvdV your right, that worked, I used the following code `=SUM(SUMIF(Table2[Franchise ID],[@[Franchise ID]],Table2[@W]),SUMIF(Table22[Franchise ID],[@[Franchise ID]],Table22[@W]),SUMIF(Table224[Franchise ID],[@[Franchise ID]],Table224[@W]))`

Answer (score 0):

The same has been answered by question owner itself through comment.

Posting that answer behalf of  @chris James Champeau

The Exact Formula Is:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Table2[Franchise ID],[@[Franchise ID]],Table2[@W]),SUMIF(Table22[Franchise ID],[@[Franchise ID]],Table22[@W]),SUMIF(Table224[Franchise ID],[@[Franchise ID]],Table224[@W]))
```